# What part need to be done in ZAP after configuration in mobile?

Tags: security, testing, mobile, owasp, zap

What part need to be done in ZAP after configuration in mobile. As I am not able to see anything in ZAP after I did the mobile configuration and opened my application in Mobile device.

Comment: Can you please be little more explicit , please see this for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agreed, more details needed :) If you are not seeing any traffic in ZAP then that implies you have not set up proxying successfully. This FAQ has some links that might prove helpful: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQmobile